# How can I tell if a SelectionChanged event was a result of UI interaction or programmatic change in the ViewModel in WPF?

Tags: wpf, events, listbox

I have a `ListBox` with a two way binding from my View Model to `SelectedItem`. When the View Model is updated, `SelectedItem` is updated and the `SelectionChanged` event is fired. `SelectionChanged` is also fired through direct user interaction in the UI e.g. clicking with mouse, touch selection, keyboard input.

I would like to perform a certain action in `SelectionChanged` *only* if the change came from UI interaction.

There appears to be properties in `SelectionChangedEventArgs` that cater to this (e.g. `OriginalSource` and `UserInitiated`) but they are not different between the two cases.

Is distinguishing between the two possible?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [SourceUpdated](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.binding.sourceupdated%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) and [TargetUpdated](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.binding.targetupdated%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) events. If you set Binding's [NotifyOnSourceUpdated](https://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev10.query?appId=Dev10IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k%28SYSTEM.WINDOWS.DATA.BINDING.NOTIFYONSOURCEUPDATED%29;k%28TargetFrameworkMoniker-%22.NETFRAMEWORK%2cVERSION%3dV4.0%22%29;k%28DevLang-CSHARP%29&rd=true) and [NotifyOnTargetUpdated](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.binding.notifyontargetupdated%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) properties to True, then you can handle those events to distinguish the source of the change:

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding TestCollection}" 
        SelectedItem="{Binding TestSelection, Mode=TwoWay, NotifyOnSourceUpdated=True, NotifyOnTargetUpdated=True}" 
        SourceUpdated="ListBox_SourceUpdated" TargetUpdated="ListBox_TargetUpdated"
        SelectionChanged="ListBox_SelectionChanged" />
```

Those events are called before `SelectionChanged` so you either can take action in their handlers or set some flag to use in SelectionChanged or whatever.

Comment: The `SourceUpdated` event does not appear to fire ever (TargetUpdated does) - I call `NotifyPropertyChanged` as appropriate in the setter of the bound property but no dice ...

Comment: @Brendan, I made more elaborate example and can confirm that both events are raised for me. I only made mistake in the order of calls - `TargetUpdated` is called after `SelectionChanged`. Maybe you missed some property setting in Binding?

Comment: Yes I assumed that these would take place *before* the binding took place, not after, hence the naming being reverse to what I expected.

Comment: Note that this unfortunately does not solve the problem, since I cannot set a flag before `SelectionChanged` - I might be able to call my code in `TargetUpdated` though ...